# Why am I not finding any output files in the desired location?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, fastq, zcat

I am trying to write a processing script and I am stuck at the beginning. It does not seem to be wrong but I cannot simply understand where the error is as it is completing the execution but not giving any output. Any debugging help?

```
#!/bin/sh    
#
# Call with following arguments
# sh test.sh  <output_basename> <fastq folder> <output_folder_loc>
#
#   
bn=$1
floc=$2
outloc=$3
#Create an output directory
#opdir=$bn"_processed"
mkdir $outloc/$bn"_processed"
echo "output directory for fastq $outloc/$bn"_processed" ..."

fout=$outloc/$bn"_processed"
echo "$fout ..."

echo "performing assembly to create one fastq file for each read mates ..."
zcat $floc/*R1*.fastq.gz > $fout/$bn_R1.fastq
zcat $floc/*R2*.fastq.gz > $fout/$bn_R2.fastq
echo "done"
```

Run command:

```
sh test.sh S_13_O1_122 /home/vdas/data/floc/Sample_S_13_O1_122_S12919 /home/vdas/data/OC/RNA-Seq/STAR_run/mut_out
```

I do not see any wrong in the code and it is also runnning without error but still am not getting any output. Can anyone point me the problem?

Comment: Add a `set -x` in the beginning of the script and run it again to see the flow of execution.

Answer (score 2):

First try to change two lines like this:

```
mkdir -p "$outloc/${bn}_processed"
fout="$outloc/${bn}_processed"
```

`mkdir -p` is good when `$outloc` directory doesn't exist yet.

Comment: or, more  correctly, mkdir -p will create the missing parts of the supplied path

Comment: Yes my bad, that for the way the parsing of the basename is being done. That was the reason it was not working. Now it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

you could test your arguments (the following may be only in bash, but do work when bash is invoked as /bin/sh)

```
var=$1
if [ ${#var} -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "var is not defined" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

that will test that the variable has some length, you might want to test other aspects as well, for instance does

```
ls $floc/*R1*.fastq.gz
```

produce any output?

Comment: I have a lot of files in the location so I am using pattern to take R1 files together in the $floc to give one file and similar for R2 and then passing them to some other commands downstream.

Comment: @vchris_ngs : that is important information that should be included in the main body of your Q. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #!/bin/sh    
 #
 # Call with following arguments
 # sh test.sh  <output_basename> <fastq folder> <output_folder_loc>
 #
 #   
 bn=$1
 floc=$2
 outloc=$3
 #Create an output directory
 #opdir=$bn"_processed"
 mkdir $outloc/$bn"_processed"
 echo "output directory for fastq $outloc/$bn"_processed" ..."

 fout=$outloc/$bn"_processed"
 echo "$fout ..."

 echo "performing assembly to create one fastq file for each read mates ..."
 echo $floc/*R1*.fastq.gz
 echo $fout/$bn_R1.fastq
 zcat -v  $floc/*R1*.fastq.gz > $fout/${bn}_R1.fastq
 zcat  -v $floc/*R2*.fastq.gz > $fout/${bn}_R2.fastq
 echo "done"
```

`

this may be wath you want,